# Command + fullstop VS Ctrl + C

Tags: keyboard, terminal, shortcut

Is there any difference between `ctrl+c` and `cmd+.` when stopping a terminal process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no difference. They both send a SIGINT signal to the running process.

You can demonstrate this using the code sample from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256709/4087178

Answer (score 1):

They are exactly the same. <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> sends `SIGINT` just like <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. I've checked this with this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
    sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print('Press Ctrl+C')
signal.pause()
```

<s>It's made this way for backward compatibility,</s> earlier versions of Apple keyboards did not have <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd> button. Please read Max Ried comment bellow.

---

<sup>code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112350/3488699</sup>

Comment: What Apple keyboard did not have a Control key? I'm not aware of any.

Comment: @MaxRied for example The Macintosh Plus Keyboard, check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Keyboard

Comment: Wow, that's legacy... From my understanding the Command-key on Apple OSes was traditionally used to issue commands, while control-key was a modifier key to Enter control characters. Up to OSX, there was no commandline, which traditionally is controlled using control characters. Thus the easy to memorable CMD+. (Read "Command full stop") was used. With the xnu Backend of OSX, Apple added the traditional Ctrl-C (Read " Cancel") as a lot of software expected it. Besides: CMD+. to interrupt Command line tasks is Terminal.app specific.

Comment: @MaxRied thanks for clarification. I've edited my post, so that future readers can see Your comment.